# Array passed into class constructor is empty - Cannot access empty property

Tags: php, class, oop, laravel-4

I am trying to pass in an array into my new class so that I always have access to the variable.

To do this:

```
class AppointmentData {

  private $date = [];

  public function __construct(Array $date)
  {
    $this->date = $date;
  }

  public function foo()
  {
    dd($this->$date);
  }

}
```

Then:

```
$appointmentData = new AppointmentData($date);
```

However when calling the function from my controller I get this error:

```
Cannot access empty property
```

Am I doing this correctly in assigning the variable in the constructor etc?

Comment: put you're dd in the constructor or wrap it in a function. You cannot post it in there as you do.
also, it is "$this->date", not "$this->$date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue:

```
public function foo()
{
  dd($this->$date);
}
```

needs to be

```
public function foo()
{
  dd($this->date);
}
```

Comment: Christ, how did I miss that. Thanks.